# Kubernetes update container image

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops

i am trying to update container image using:

```
kubectl set image deployment/deployment name container name=
newimage:39
```

but facing this error

error: all resources must be specified before image changes:

Comment: it should be `kubectl set image deployment/%deploymentname% %containername%=image:tag` where `%%` represent things you have to replace with your values

Comment: I think this should not be done at first place , u need to re-deploy with always pull, all changes should orginate from version control othervise u will get into trouble

Comment: well, its debatable, really. I've had release builds that were just updating the image to the specific version tied with the release. its just a matter of what deployment model you are using

Comment: Nope , its not debatlable at all , the best well know pattern is to triger the docker build from version control , that tirggers the kubernetes deploymenet at the end , directly editing things in kubernetes is a well know anti pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   kubectl set image deployment/<deployment-name> <container-name>=$IMAGE
```

You can also try patch the deployment

```
kubectl patch deployment/deployment_name --patch "{\"spec\": {\"template\": {\"spec\": {\"initContainers\": [{\"name\": \"container_name\",\"image\": \"url_to_container\"}]}}}}"
```